# Having trouble with socket.io chat

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

I am having issues with a basic socket.io chat. I am just trying to send basic text to console for now, however I can't seem to get it to work. I either get: null, which it is not sending the message and then clearing the field. Or if I change the id to the input instead of the form I get it to where it wont reload the whole page, and it'll throw undefined errors from globals inside the file itself, that are definitely defined.

So here is the socket.io chat code for the back-end:

```
// Socket stuff
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('User Connected');
  socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});
```

Here is the jQuery function:

```
  // Handles Chat
  $('#chat').load('chat.ejs', function () {
      $('#chatMessage').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var msg = $('#chatMessage input[type=text]').val();

        $('chatMessage input[type=text]').val('');

        if (!connected || msg == '') {
          return false;
        }

        socket.emit('chat message', msg);
      });
    });
```

And here is the ejs it is using:

```
<style>
  #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
  #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
</style>
<body>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<form id="chatMessage" action="">
  <input autocomplete="off" />
</form>
```

With it like it is now, when I push enter it'll return null, and not clear the text from the input. If I move the id to to the input instead of the form, it'll sometimes throw undefined on global variables that are defined, or it'll just reload the whole page without doing anything.

EDIT:
Okay I took this function out of the `$('#chat').load()` function and added it after `$(document).ready()` and I'm not sure if it did anything, but it seems like it is submitting, but it is reloading the page as a whole, and not sending a console log message to show the message.

EDIT 2: 
I decided I should show the error it throws every once in awhile after the function submits:

```
ReferenceError: /home/kogadmin/www/views/game.ejs:73
    71|                 <form name="mobget">

    72|                   <select>

 >> 73|                   <% for (var i = 0; i < mobs.length; ++i) { %>

    74|                       <option name="mobs" value="<%= mobs[i].id %>"><%= mobs[i].name %></option>

    75|                   <% } %>

    76|                   </select>


mobs is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:59:28)
    at returnedFn (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:580:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:223:34)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:437:10)
    at View.render (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at /home/kogadmin/www/server.js:108:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

This variable IS defined, and it only throws this after submitting this function.

Comment: One small typo to note: `$('chatMessage input[type=text]').val('');` is missing the `#` in the ID

Comment: Can you also please show the code from `game.ejs`?

Comment: You've also lost me slightly with all your edits, and appear to be asking several questions at once. Other than the typo, the code you've provided doesn't seem to have any major issues. Also, you can't set up the event handler until the jQuery load has completed, so your original code is correct, not the edit

Comment: Oh, I meant to say that I have fixed this. For some reason `'#chatMessage input[type=text]'` wouldn't work so I just had to also give the input element a id and use it for the input value. Although I now have a whole new issue of bringing in data from back-end to front-end, such as username from database when logged in while sending a chat message